# How to get word2vec training loss in Gensim from pretrained models?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I have some pre-trained word2vec model and I'd like to evaluate them using the same corpus. Is there a way I could get the raw training loss given a model dump file and the corpus in memory?

Answer (score 0):

The training-loss reporting of gensim's `Word2Vec` (& related models) is a newish feature that doesn't quite yet work the way most people expect.

For example, at least through gensim 3.7.1 (January 2019), you can just retrieve the total loss since the last call to `train()` (across multiple epochs). Some [pending changes](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2135) may eventually change that.

The loss-tallying is only done if requested when the model is created, via the `compute_loss` parameter. So if the model wasn't initially configured with this setting there will be no loss data inside it about prior training.

You could presumably tamper with the loaded model, `w2v_model.compute_loss = False`, so that further calls to `train()` (with the same or new data) would collect loss data. However, note that such training will also be updating the model, with respect the current data.

You could also look at the `score()` method, available for some model modes, which reports a loss-related number for batches of new texts, **without** changing the model. It may essentially work as a way to assess whether new texts "seem like" the original training data. See the method docs, including links to the motivating academic paper and an example notebook, for more info:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.score

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have any ideas besides calculating loss that could evaluate a model?

Answer (score 0):

@John M., to subjectively evaluate the model, you could list words similar to a particular word, and check if those "similar" words make sense. This is shown [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html):

```
model.wv.most_similar('computer', topn=10)
```

P.S: I can't reply to your comment since my reputation isn't high enough